# mustache populate JSON object error

Tags: javascript, html, json, asp.net-mvc, mustache

I have code below. I need to populate a JSON object using mustache. Unfortunately, it shows nothing to me.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = "[{"PR_ID":23096,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33232,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33308,"P_ID":23014},{"PR_ID":33309,"P_ID":23014}]";
    var template = $("#template").html();
    Mustache.parse(template);
    var rendered = Mustache.render(template, data);
    $('#PatrList').html(rendered);
 </script>

<body>
    <div id="PatrList"></div>

    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        {{ #. }}
            <div>
                PR_ID: <h2> {{PR_ID}} </h2> ---- P_ID: <h2> {{P_ID}} </h2>
            </div>
        {{ /. }}
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have `""` around your array. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y9869m7j/).

Comment: @NickRussler , The data is returned value from c# Code:var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(patrs); So how to format it to the properly way can be accepted by mustache?

Comment: @NickRussler, How to remove javascript string "" , then use it ?

Comment: literally just delete the "" surrounding the array stored as "data"

Comment: @TeddyWard, Thanks for your reply. Can you give me code example on how to delete the "" surrounding the array stored as "data", please. :-)

Comment: You could pass the String into `Json.parse` or [eval](http://xkr.us/js/eval) but the problem is that "[{"PR_ID":230[...]" is not even a valid JavaScript String because the delimiter appears within the String..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `var data` is a string and not an object. You need to remove the outer quotation marks or parse the string to an object (given that the delimiter is escaped properly within the string) e.g. with [JSON.parse(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [eval](http://xkr.us/js/eval)